# insert into database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

```
<?php
include("dbinit.php");
$text="helow";
    $eadd = $_SESSION['account'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM account where Eadd='". $eadd ."'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $name = $row['Name'];
            }
                $ctext = $_POST['ctext'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO chat (By, Content, Reported) VALUES ('$name','$ctext','No')";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                mysqli_close($link);
                $text=$name . $ctext;
echo $text;
?>
```

Here is my code. In my other page, this works but .. when i change the values in "insert into" why i cant store it to database?

```
<?php
session_start();
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
        }
        mysqli_select_db($link, "xxx");
        header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

here is my dbinit file

Comment: Read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Or simply think about what will happen if the posted text contains a single quote.

Comment: yes i read it.. about pdo.. :).. but.. i am going to do this first. after i know how to create a chatbox. i will now going to have change it to pdo.. thanks

Comment: You don't need pdo to avoid SQL injection. Why make things wrong from the start? Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what else i can use to avoid sql injection? i make it because i want to know the basic first..:)

Comment: Follow the link I gave you, and learn to use prepared statements. They are what avoids SQL injection.

Comment: thanks to all of you!. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BY` is reserved keyword you should use backticks around it

```
     $sql = "INSERT INTO chat (`By`, Content, Repo.........
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `chat` (`By`, `Content`, `Reported`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$ctext."','No')";
```

[to protect from mysql injections read this.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

also, what kind of values did you change to that doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the PHP variables in your $sql with double quotes, don't forget the dots.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO chat (By, Content, Reported) VALUES ('".$name."','".$ctext."','No')";
```

Comment: This won't make any difference, as he has used double quotes the PHP interpreter will treat them as variables regardless, so there's no need to do this.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php